# Select multiple data from tables with sum and count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, where-clause

My MySQL structure

```
create table product(id integer(11), name varchar(100));

create table purchase(id_purchase integer(11), user_id integer(11), id_product integer(11), cost integer(11));

insert into product values (1,'product1');
insert into product values (2,'product2');
insert into product values (3,'product3');
insert into product values (4,'product4');

insert into purchase values (1, 1, 4, 10);
insert into purchase values (2, 1, 4, 5);
insert into purchase values (3, 1, 2, 16);
```

I need this result

```
id_product | sum(cost) | count
------------------------------
1             0          0
2             16         1
3             0          0
4             15         2
```

grouping by id product for one user

Please help me.

Comment: What have you looked at so far? (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you made a lot of research before asking this question...

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT PR.id
     ,SUM(P.cost) AS [sum(cost)]
     ,SUM(CASE
             WHEN P.id_product IS NOT NULL THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [count]
FROM product PR
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase P ON P.id_product = PR.id
                            AND P.user_id = ...
GROuP BY PR.id
ORDER BY PR.id
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This way get only record for exist purchase product. I need statistic by all product ids

Comment: I fixed my query, with this `LEFT OUTER JOIN`there will be one row for each existing product and the corresponding statistics. Can you test it?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select id,case when cost is null then 0 else cost end as sum,
case when p.cnt is null then 0 else p.cnt end as count from
product left join (select id_product,sum(cost) as cost,
count(*) as cnt from purchase group by id_product ) as p on
id=id_product group by id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa798/10)

Comment: This way work only for one user_id in table. For many user_id calculate not correct